# Multivalue parameter in PostgreSQL function

Tags: jasper-reports

I am having a *PostgreSQL* function:

```sql
func(timestamp,timestamp,Integer[],varchar[])
```

I want to design a *JasperReports* report to fetch data from the function. For this, I created parameter of type list to take input from user and pass it as *varchar* array.

For this, I am trying to use the following query:

```sql
select * from func($P{interval_start}::timestamp,$P{interval_end}::timestamp,array[$P!{idParameter}],array[$P!{usersParameter}])
```

But when I am running the report, it gives error like `column user1(passed from parameter) does not exist`.

I also tried:

```sql
select * from func($P{interval_start}::timestamp,$P{interval_end}::timestamp,array[$P!{idParameter}],array[$P{usersParameter}])
```

But it says:

```
 Compiling to file... /home/Prashant/Desktop/jasper-report/report2.jasper
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid : 
1. Parameter type not supported in query : usersParameter class java.util.Collection 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.verifyDesign(JRAbstractCompiler.java:258)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:140) 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:212) 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:128) 
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:516) 
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)    
  at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997) 
Compilation running time: 73!
```

Please suggest, how to pass string array to *PostgreSQL* function from *iReport*?

Comment: If all else fails, concatenate your integer array and your text array into two strings with delimiters, pass them as `text`, then parse them in the SQL function. First, though, try passing a Java `String[]` and `int[]` instead of a `List<String>` and `List<Integer>`.

Comment: Thanks @CraigRinger, I can definitely write a wrapper function to parse the parameters, but I was wondering if there is not any way in iReport to pass the String array directly.  Also, how can we define a parameter to be of type Java String[]?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Where you're passing a `Collection` like a `List<String>` to Jasper, pass a `String[]` instead. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html . The `Collections.toArray` method can be useful here.

Comment: @CraigRinger I know Collections.toArray, I don't know how to use it in iReports.  One more question, is there any way in JasperReports Server to check how many times a report is run?

Comment: so iReports has its own language, not plain Java? In that case, honestly not sure what to do except parse strings in the function. As for the 2nd, maybe call an SQL function that does a `RAISE NOTICE` and use csvlog or grep the logs? Or if iReport lets you call functions written in Java, connect to a RESTful web service on the server?